# How to go to next window in MVVM (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, window

I'm just a beginner in programming wpf and MVVM.
I have to make a sort of wizard to create or delete or edit something. So my first window is a menu with 3 or more buttons. When you click on one of these buttons you go to the next screen.. I was able to do this with the code behind with window.show(), but i read that it is a lot better to programm with the mvvm pattern.
Someone who can help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Ruben, exactly what is your question?  How to use MVVM?  That's better solved by reading an article or two on the subject or watching one of the many video tutorials that are out there in my opinion.  There are certainly some MVVM-related questions here on SO that would help you grok the concept, but a tutorial is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

For a wizard, use a [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615518.aspx) to navigate among [Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article about it: [Creating an Internationalized Wizard in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx).